# Stop nginx service that is started from docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, windows-10

I was watching nginx tutorial and for the purpose of follow up, I created Ubuntu 18.04 docker container. I installed and started nginx service as shown as in the tutorial and everything was going well. Then I removed both docker image and container that I'm working on. Despite removal of container and image, "http://104.200.23.232/" this address on my machine still returns nginx welcome page. As I think, this indicates that nginx service is still up and running. My question is that how can I stop and disable auto start of nginx service now?

*Note:* My host machine operating system is Windows 10 and restarting computer did not help to solve this problem.

Comment: Use [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) to find container, then use  [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) to stop it

Comment: @ponury-kostek thanks for answer. But as I stated in my question container from which I started nginx service was stopped and removed already.

Comment: @ponury-kostek My issue is not to stop docker container. Please read the post carefully.

Comment: @nicat9507 are you sure that nginx is not installed on your machine ?

Comment: @nicat9507 add output of `docker ps` command to problem, also other details like how you are starting services like using docker compose or docker cli

Comment: @GaneshKarewad No, it is not installed.

Comment: @GaneshKarewad "docker ps" returns an empty list. And I started nginx on container (which is removed now) by running "service nginx start".

Comment: so its mean the nginx is running somewhere on host machine

Comment: @Adiii yes. What I want is to stop nginx on host machine and also disable it starting on startup.

Comment: nginx -s stop in powershell, or also open your task manager and kill the process,  or also you can try `taskkill /F /IM nginx.exe`

Comment: https://www.technipages.com/delete-services

Comment: @Adiii I tried both of them. They return an error "nginx not found", since nginx is not installed on host machine.

Comment: okay goto your task manager and search for nignx and kill them :P

Comment: @Adiii Problem is that I can't find any trace of nginx on host machine. I am afraid that I will have to reinstall operating system for stopping nginx. :D

Comment: hahaha no no, do not do that :P go to the program file and find it here and the remove dash nginx ;)

Comment: I am just continuing to watch the tutorial and restart nginx service on container. Let me see where life will take me... :D

Comment: good luck ;) thats why i hate window :P

Comment: yeah life is good until you open the windows.

Comment: let me know once u done

Comment: it has nothing to do windows, it happens on Macos also, thats why i just came to this post. Have you found a working solution here? I have also no container running but Localhost:8080 which used for nginx is returning the home page?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, well blind guessing here but the IP "104.200.23.232" is registered for Linode which is a cloudhosting/vps provider, right? so probably not the IP of your local computer. Where did you get the reference for this ip? Did you try or install something on a cloudserver? I am pretty sure there are just some things mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Use "prune" to start fresh:

```
docker system prune
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to stop nginx in docker container:

```
service nginx stop
```

Comment: By and large commands like `service` don't work in Docker containers.  A container usually only runs a single process and you can't stop that process separately from the container; it's generally not running any sort of init system that could handle `service` commands.